# Is it polite to ask for acknowledgement of transcript received at university

Tags: graduate-admissions, international-students

I have been offered admission in one of the top Canadian University. After admission I have sent them my transcripts from India. This transcripts were supposed to reach by 23 May but I have no acknowledgement from their side. Should I ask for the acknowledgement from them?

Another important issue, although, in Letter of Acceptance they have specifically mentioned "Accepted" but they have also added the condition of receiving transcripts. Will this be an issue for obtaining study permit?

Comment: Can you send an unofficial transcript by email, as preliminary documentation?  Also, were they sent with tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already accepted and they are asking you for materials, it is perfectly acceptable to correspond with them quite regularly to follow up and ensure everything goes smoothly. In fact, I would very strongly encourage you to do so, because paperwork is easily lost, misplaced, or delayed until it creates quite the inconvenience for you!

A script such as this would be quite fine:

- email them that you have sent the transcripts and they are supposed to arrive by X date (you are past this point, but it is good to know for the future)
- email them 1-3 days latter (depending on the urgency of any deadlines), and tell them you were told the transcripts would arrive by X date, and would you kindly confirm if you have received them?

If 3-5 days pass without confirmation or other reply, feel free to politely follow up and ping them again. Something of the general form "don't want to be a bother, but I know how bad international mail can be [you are giving them a polite 'out' so it isn't them being slow, it's probably someone else's fault], but have my required transcripts been received?"

If another 3-5 days pass and you still haven't heard anything - or sooner if you are running against any kind of important deadlines that you are aware of - feel free to escalate the issue with a call to the office, contacting someone else in the hierarchy (director of the grad program, for instance), etc.

None of this is impolite - it's just how things work. You are ultimately responsible for not falling through the cracks, because you are the one who pays the greatest cost of things get lost in the shuffle. You can be polite in your phrasing (but at least in the US no need to be excessively deferential - just clear, to the point, but with a touch of politeness and please and thank you), but following up and making sure things are received and acceptable with reasonable time to process inbetween is both fine and highly suggested!